# php / mysql prepared statement form issue INSERT INTO

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

The code below takes in information from a form and sends it to mysql. It did so successfully (for category,contents,date, and userid) but recently I added a new column in the database called 'seclevel' that needs to be filled as well.  I'm not seeing a logical reason why the addition of seclevel has broken the code, and I receive no errors in the log. It's just a user selected integer from 1-9 so unless I'm using $_POST['seclevel'] incorrectly I'm stumped. Any ideas?

send_post.php

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';
sec_session_start();

$userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
if(login_check($mysqli) == true) {

//Connecting to sql db.
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","mylogin","mypass","mydb");

header("Location: http://somekindasite.com/index_3.php");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Fail"; } else { echo "Success"; }

//Sending form data to sql db.
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('INSERT INTO opwire (category, contents, date, userid, seclevel) 
                            VALUES (?,?,NOW(),?,?)');
$stmt -> bind_param('ssi', $_POST['category'], $_POST['contents'], $userId, $_POST['seclevel']);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> close();

} else {
   echo 'Access denied. <br/>';
}

?>
```

Here is the relevant form that submits to send_post.php

```
<html>
<div style="width:  330px;  height:  130px;  overflow:  auto;">
<form STYLE="color: #f4d468;" action="send_post.php" method="post">

    Category: <select STYLE="color: #919191; font-family: Veranda; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10px; background-color: #000000;" name="category">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="1">2</option>
<option value="1">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option STYLE="color: #c31717;" value="8">8</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>

    Seclevel: <select STYLE="color: #919191; font-family: Veranda; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10px; background-color: #000000;" name="seclevel">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select> <br>

    <textarea overflow: scroll; rows="4" cols="60" STYLE="color: #919191; font-family: Veranda; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10px; background-color: #000000; width:300px; height:80px; margin:0; padding:0;" name="contents"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" STYLE="color: #919191; font-family: Veranda; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10px; background-color: #000000;" value="Create Log">
</form>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: In your `bind_param()` you have just `ssi` but you are in fact binding 4 parameters.

Comment: Looks like you need to make that into `ssii`

Comment: Ahhh crap, I always miss the small things.  Thank you I'll try popping that in quick.

Comment: That's got it. Thanks again.  If you put it in answer form I can send you the upvote and checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQLi's parameter binding has two parts, and you missed one of them. You need to add the type `s` for string or `i` for integer (or `d` double, `b` blob) into the first argument to `bind_param()`.

```
// Looks like you're adding another integer...
$stmt -> bind_param('ssii', $_POST['category'], $_POST['contents'], $userId, $_POST['seclevel']);
//---------------------^^^
```

Since [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param()` returns `FALSE` on failure](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), you ought to put in some error checking.

```
if ($stmt->bind_param('ssii', $_POST['category'], $_POST['contents'], $userId, $_POST['seclevel'])) {
  $stmt->execute();
}
else {
  echo $stmt->error;
}
```

I'll also note that I would expect `bind_param()` to have issued a fatal error.  When developing code, it's always recommended to crank up error reporting and show errors on screen.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```